# Program Times Out When Only Blank Newline Is Entered

Tags: c++

The assignment was to write a program that receives numbers as an inputs (each one on a new line) and then sorts them from smallest to largest. The way to end the input is to enter a blank newline after the numbers are entered. My program works fine except for when I enter only a blank line. Then the program times out.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void sort(vector<int>& v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        int min = i;
        for(int j = i; j < v.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(v[j] < v[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if(min != i){
            int temp = v[min];
            v[min] = v[i];
            v[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void print(vector<int> v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << v[i];
        if(i != v.size() - 1)
        {
            cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter integers (one on each line, entering an empty line quits):" << endl;
    vector<int> v;
    string str;
    while(getline(cin, str))
    {
        if(str == "")
        {
            cout << "Sorted: ";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            v.push_back(atoi(str.c_str()));
        }
    }

    sort(v);
    print(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "time out"? Are you perhaps running the program in an environment where execution time is limited? Further, does your code still contain parts that aren't called then? If so, you should remove them to get closer to the minimal example as per guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't check for empty vector in sort() and v.size() - 1 causes integer underflow. Add check for empty vector:

```
void sort(vector<int>& v)
{
    if (!v.empty()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
        {
            int min = i;
            for(int j = i; j < v.size(); ++j)
            {
                if(v[j] < v[min])
                {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            if(min != i){
                int temp = v[min];
                v[min] = v[i];
                v[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```